# No 'Home Site' attribute has been provided for 'Office2003PIA'

Tags: .net, deployment, ms-office

I have Office 2003 PIA as dependency in my setup project.
when I build my project I'm getting following Warning.

---

Warning 1   No 'HomeSite' attribute has been provided for 'Office 2003 PIAs', so the package will be published to the same location as the bootstrapper.

Comment: how to solve this problem so I can remove this warning while building my application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem with Office 2007 PIA so I assume there will either be a similar solution or it can't be done.

The best answer I have found so far implies that it isn't possible :

http://blogs.msdn.com/vsto/archive/2008/05/20/common-pitfalls-during-pia-deployment-and-installation.aspx